# how to choose a random item from arrays nested in an object

Tags: javascript

I'm trying a project that will choose a random answer out of one of the 3 nested arrays in my object. My goal is to know afterwards out of which array the answer came, so I can use that to know what the new sentence will be.

The example below works with 1 array, but i want to know if the answer is a good, bad or doubt answer, hence why i put it in an object.

EDIT: code below gives me a random property in my object, but i need to go one step deeper. The comment next to it is what i tried but it gives me undefined.

```
const randomAnswers = {
goodAnswers: ['yes','Absolutely','certainly',"I'm sure",'HELL YES'],
maybes: ['maybe','probably','perhaps',"honestly man, i really don't 
know this one"],
badAnswers: ['LOL NO','no way man','maybe',"forget it",'HELL no','Are 
you serious?']
};
{

const init = () => {
console.log("initiated");
let answer = document.querySelector('.answer');
answer.style.opacity = 0;

setTimeout(fixSentence,3000);
//fixSentence();
}

const fixSentence = () => {
    let a = document.querySelector('.answer');
    let think = document.querySelector('.think');
    console.log('shown');
    console.log(a.textContent);
    let randomAnswer = randomAnswers[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomAnswers.length)];

    var randomProperty = function (obj) {
        var keys = Object.keys(obj)
        let random = obj[keys[ keys.length * Math.random() << 0]];
        return random/*[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomAnswers.length)]*/;
    };

    console.log(randomProperty(randomAnswers))

    let splittedSentence = a.textContent.split(" ");
    console.log(splittedSentence);
    a.textContent = `${randomAnswer}`;
    a.style.opacity = 1;
    think.style.opacity = 0;
}

init();
```

}

the output of console.log(randomAnswer) is obviously undefined right now, but I can't figure out how to choose a random item out of one of the three arrays in the object.

Comment: One question is what probability you want? Want to have a higher probability for bad answer just because you have more ways of giving a bad answer? Or do you want the same probability (1/3) to have a good, maybe or bad answer?

Comment: Actually, it would be nice if it wouldn't pick the same array 2 times after eachother.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```js
const randomAnswers = {
  goodAnswers: ['yes','Absolutely','certainly',"I'm sure",'HELL YES'],
  maybes: ['maybe','probably','perhaps',"honestly man, i really don't know this one"],
  badAnswers: ['LOL NO','no way man','maybe',"forget it",'HELL no','Are you serious?']
};

const randomNumber = function(subject) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random()*subject.length);
}

const types = Object.keys(randomAnswers);
const randomTypeNumber = randomNumber(types);
const randomType = types[randomTypeNumber];

const randomAnswerNumber = randomNumber(randomAnswers[randomType]);
const randomAnswer = randomAnswers[randomType][randomAnswerNumber];

console.log( { randomType, randomAnswer } );
```

You pick a random key from the object, and then pick a random element from that array by using `Object.keys(randomAnswers).length` and subsequently that array length for the random numbers.